# Flutter how to draw pressable rectangle on camera feed?

Tags: flutter, camera, rectangles, bounding-box

I'm using `camera` plug-in to get the camera feed. Every 10 seconds, I generate 4 values `(x,y,w,h)` and draw a rectangle (only the border, the inside is transparent) on the screen (with random text). If the user clicks on this box, it disappears.

It looks something like this image. `(x,y,w,h)` and the text are randomly generated.

[image]

Is this possible to do this using `camera` plugin? Or is there another package that already does this?

Comment: Camera plugin does not have this feature. You would have to custom build this.

Comment: So the plugin doesn't have pressable rectangle. But does it have built-in function to draw a rectangle?

Comment: Camera plugin does not have feature to draw a rectangle, but you could wrap your camera output with Stack widget and draw the bounding box with it. I could write you a sample code if that would be helpful.

Comment: @dshukertjr Yes please! A sample code would be very helpful. If possible, adding a text on top of that rectangle (or inside the rectangle, like the above image) is also helpful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Camera plugin does not have any feature to draw over the preview, but you can make something like that with Stack widget and containers.

Here's a quick and dirty example, but hopefully will give you the idea:

```
class CameraApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CameraAppState createState() => _CameraAppState();
}

class _CameraAppState extends State<CameraApp> {
  CameraController controller;

  // Holds the position information of the rectangle
  Map<String, double> _position = {
    'x': 0,
    'y': 0,
    'w': 0,
    'h': 0,
  };

  // Whether or not the rectangle is displayed
  bool _isRectangleVisible = false;

  Future<void> getCameras() async {
    final cameras = await availableCameras();
    controller = CameraController(cameras[0], ResolutionPreset.medium);
    controller.initialize().then((_) {
      if (!mounted) {
        return;
      }
      setState(() {});
    });
  }

  // Some logic to get the rectangle values
  void updateRectanglePosition() {
    setState(() {
      // assign new position
      _position = {
        'x': 0,
        'y': 0,
        'w': 0,
        'h': 0,
      };
      _isRectangleVisible = true;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    getCameras();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (!controller.value.isInitialized) {
      return Container();
    }
    return Stack(
      children: [
        AspectRatio(
          aspectRatio: controller.value.aspectRatio,
          child: controller == null ? Container() : CameraPreview(controller),
        ),
        if (_isRectangleVisible)
          Positioned(
            left: _position['x'],
            top: _position['y'],
            child: InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                // When the user taps on the rectangle, it will disappear
                setState(() {
                  _isRectangleVisible = false;
                });
              },
              child: Container(
                width: _position['w'],
                height: _position['h'],
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border.all(
                    width: 2,
                    color: Colors.blue,
                  ),
                ),
                child: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    child: Text(
                      'hourse -71%',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I get "NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'value' was called on null" . My main() is just "WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized(); runApp(new CameraApp());"

Maybe something is missing?

Comment: @DukeLe I just edited my answer a bit, but there maybe some small errors. What I want you to get out of this code is the basic idea of how to use Stack widget to draw over camera preview.